# Embedding a css file into internal <style> elments

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, filesystems

I am trying to dynamically swap through different stylesheets. Because I am using React, the stylesheets that I require() get embedded into the html as "style" elements.
What I tried to do was to remove the old style elements and create new ones, which contain the new stylesheet.
I have realized, however, that it is not trivial to "insert" the content from my newstyle.css into the `<style>` element that I just created.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

What I have tried is reading my .css file by using a xhttp GET request but I failed. There are a few questions about this specific topic, but I suspect that the situation is different in React because it seems like I can not just provide a simple relative path to my style.css to the xhttp GET.

I also looked for React specific file-readers but generally didn't find very much. Maybe my approach of "manually" reading the file is unfit for a project that uses of React, node etc.

Thank you for any help, I hope this question is not redundant or vague.

Comment: If the styles are all preset, maybe putting them all under a differing class and just switching the root element to that class might do as a hack for now?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
const newCSS = document.createElement('link');
newCSS.href = `/path/to/templates/${style}.css`;
newCSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(newCSS);
```

Comment: I tried this aswell and it probably is possible to do it this way but I didnt get it to work yet. I suspect that was because the path wasnt correct. Does it just need to lead from the script file to the stylesheet? Ill try this again tomorrow